# Problem related to NavigationLink in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new to swiftUI and I meet the error "Updating took more than 5 seconds" when I add the following code

```
@State var studentclass = "default"
@State var studentNumber = "default"
@State var targetedArrayIndex : Int = 1
@State var isActive = false
.
.
.
.
.
NavigationLink(destination: Result(result : results[targetedArrayIndex]), isActive: $isActive) {

    Button(action: {

      if studentclass == "1A" && studentNumber == "01" {targetedArrayIndex = 0}
      if studentclass == "1A" && studentNumber == "02" {targetedArrayIndex = 1}
      if studentclass == "1A" && studentNumber == "03" {targetedArrayIndex = 2}
      .
      .
      .
      .
      self.isLinkActive = true

      }) {.....}
```

In the above code, I am trying to read the result of a particular student from a json file stored in an array. I created a dropdown menu that allow user to select studentclass and studentNumber. Hence, I use the IF/THEN statement to judge the array index of the targeted student. However, once I pass the targetedArrayObject to Result.swift (which is another view for displaying student's result), Xcode report an error.

For debuging, I tried to replace the varible targetedArrayObject by 0, i.e.

`NavigationLink(destination: Result(result : results[0]), isActive: $isActive) {.....}`

It works and shows the result sucessfully. So I get confused of why I get an error in the first case.

Comment: You get this error when you have too much logic going into the view. You need to find smarter/shorter ways to do this filtering. Based on your code snip, you should probably be using a ForEach loop. ... If you ever find yourself typing if a, if b, if c, if d, if e ... then there's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works to use ForEach loop instead of if/then loop !